# Помогите переписать с jquery на чистый js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите переписать с jquery на чистый js.

Ни как не разберусь.

```
$('.dynamic_inputs').each(function() { $(this).val(findUtms(this.getAttribute("name"))) });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic_inputs');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = findUtms(inputs[i].getAttribute("name"));
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!